# Optimizing a query : joining a table on itself

Tags: mysql

i want to get last two row of a table in one query as new data and previous data

i got

```
 select tbl.x , tbl2.x as last_x 
 from tbl left join tbl tbl2 ON tbl.id!= tbl2.id
 order by tbl.id desc , tbl2.id desc limit 1
```

it works fine but i think it might get slow in a big DB

is there any way to make this faster ?

Comment: can you give sample records?

Comment: @max Am I crazy or why does `SELECT * FROM tbl ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 2` not do the trick?

Comment: @tombom - I take it that he wants some details from both rows returned in a single record.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A LIMIT should work in a basic subquery, and so the following will possibly be more efficient

```
SELECT Sub1.x , Sub2.x as last_x 
FROM (SELECT x FROM tbl ORDER BY tbl.id DESC LIMIT 1) Sub1
CROSS JOIN (SELECT x FROM tbl ORDER BY tbl.id DESC LIMIT 2, 1) Sub2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at the [execution plan](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/using-explain.html) and try to optimize your query, but usually you do this when you face a problem so you can determine which parts are taking long.

Chick this thread to: [How to optimise MySQL queries based on EXPLAIN plan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10148851/how-to-optimise-mysql-queries-based-on-explain-plan)

But as saied i would not try to solve a problm which still does not exist, i do not actually see a problem aith your query.