# MySQL statement takes more than minute to execute

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a website in which the database is huge. 1 million records are in the table at the time. When I perform a query then it takes too much time to execute. One sample query is given below:

```
select * from `ratings` order by id limit 499500, 500
```

Every query takes more than one minute, but when I drop the table to 10 thousand records then this query executes fastly.

As I have read that there is not problem for 1 million records in a table because in database tables, there is not problem of big records.

I have used indexing of id in the table by the help of Stack Overflow question *[How do I add indices to MySQL tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002605/how-to-add-indexes-to-mysql-tables)*, but still I got the same problem.

*** I am using [CodeIgniter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codeigniter#CodeIgniter) for the project.

Comment: Do you use [indexes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimization-indexes.html) in your table? Also, 1M records is not that big for MySQL.

Comment: table has three columns ranking_id, id and website....
i have not concept of indexing... but there should not be a problem for 1M records

Comment: indexes in place? You are bringing back 500 rows, not 1M (or half that)

Comment: yeah, a table index is a good practice

Comment: There should be a problem if no indexes are used. You definitely need an index on `id`

Comment: from the manual `SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT 5,10;  # Retrieve rows 6-15`

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos i have used indexed but still same problem.

Comment: Can you give a snapshot of the execution plan of the query. That should be helpful for all of us.

Comment: SELECT * is a problem, ORDER BY LIMIT X ,y can only be accomplished by a scan,it has to get all the rows before ordering them

Comment: If this is for pagination don't let people page in to arbitrary page numbers like 1,000.

Comment: That query requires stepping over 499500 row before getting to the 500 you want.  That takes time, regardless of the indexing.  Why the heck do you want to do that?

Comment: @Mihai - if there is an index exactly matching the `ORDER BY`, it may use the index and not have to "get **all** the rows", but only 500000 in this case.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Note, this is not suggesting for a minute to use MyISAM. I use that only to get my ids, min,max, and count to line up. So ignore the engine, please.

```sql
create table ratings
(   id int auto_increment primary key,
    thing int null
)engine=MyISAM;
insert ratings (thing) values (null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null);
insert ratings (thing) select thing from ratings;
insert ratings (thing) select thing from ratings;
insert ratings (thing) select thing from ratings;
insert ratings (thing) select thing from ratings;
insert ratings (thing) select thing from ratings;
insert ratings (thing) select thing from ratings;
insert ratings (thing) select thing from ratings;
insert ratings (thing) select thing from ratings;
insert ratings (thing) select thing from ratings;
insert ratings (thing) select thing from ratings;

insert ratings (thing) select thing from ratings;
insert ratings (thing) select thing from ratings;
insert ratings (thing) select thing from ratings;
insert ratings (thing) select thing from ratings;
insert ratings (thing) select thing from ratings;
insert ratings (thing) select thing from ratings;
insert ratings (thing) select thing from ratings;

insert ratings (thing) select thing from ratings;
insert ratings (thing) select thing from ratings;
```

**I now have 4.7M rows**

```
select count(*),min(id),max(id) from ratings;
+----------+---------+---------+
| count(*) | min(id) | max(id) |
+----------+---------+---------+
|  4718592 |       1 | 4718592 |
+----------+---------+---------+
select * from `ratings` order by id limit 499500, 500;
-- 1 second on a dumpy laptop
```

.

```
explain select * from `ratings` order by id limit 499500, 500;
+----+-------------+---------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+----------------+
| id | select_type | table   | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows    | Extra          |
+----+-------------+---------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+----------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | ratings | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 4718592 | Using filesort |
+----+-------------+---------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+----------------+
```

.

```
explain select * from `ratings` where id>=499501 limit 500;
+----+-------------+---------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+---------+-----------------------+
| id | select_type | table   | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows    | Extra                 |
+----+-------------+---------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+---------+-----------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | ratings | range | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | NULL | 4198581 | Using index condition |
+----+-------------+---------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+---------+-----------------------+
```

Moral of the story may be to use a where clause.

One cannot rule out the possibility of a deadlock.

Comment: Thanks. by where condition and order by, its working.

Comment: ">=" only works if there are no gaps in the ids!  (And, yes, InnoDB and MyISAM should work similarly for _this_ case.)

Comment: @RickJames the engine was chosen because innodb would have caused range allocation gaps during the self-inserts

Comment: One can always mess with the innodb mode like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38363271) but I basically wasn't up for it at the moment.

Comment: or an `ALTER TABLE table_name ENGINE=InnoDB;`

Answer (score 1):

Start with checking the execution plan of the query to identify the bottleneck and create indexes if required. I think you should atleast have a index on Id column.

There are many factors which can also affect your query performance:

1. Fragmentation of Data pages
2. Statistics of table not updated
3. Many request running in parallel

and many more....

Follow the below links to get the execution plan and to identify the performance degrading factors:
http://www.sitepoint.com/using-explain-to-write-better-mysql-queries/

[How to optimise MySQL queries based on EXPLAIN plan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10148851/how-to-optimise-mysql-queries-based-on-explain-plan)

Let me know if you face any troubles.

Answer (score 1):

Checklist:

- Created clustered index (index) on 'id' column order by ASC
- Check your query time from command line, [see this](http://ronaldbradford.com/blog/timing-your-sql-queries-2010-07-07/)
- Check your [PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP) code (I see you using **CodeIgniter**). About your algorithm: Did you use the CodeIgniter database library [see this](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/queries.html)?
   If you are using a raw query, check your loop.

Alternative way is to try a query using to an active index:

```
select * from `ratings` where id>=456789 limit 500;
```

Answer (score 0):

Check for indexing. There should be a primary key in each table
and there may attributes in your `where` clause of your query that are not part of the primary index or of a clustered index.

Comment: I am not using where condition in the query.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the [InnoDB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/InnoDB) engine for your table, change it to [MyISAM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MyISAM). It is faster for read operations. [When to use MyISAM and InnoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15678406/when-to-use-myisam-and-innodb).

In addition, if you have queries with search criteria, make sure frequently used column are indexed.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the link of Tuts-plus which will help you to solve your problem .

Most Probable solution is indexing the database and instead of (*) use column names  [Better way to Query](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/top-20-mysql-best-practices--net-7855)