# Is it possible to use a subquery IN clause over an aggregate?

Tags: mysql

So I have the following normal query:

```
SELECT 
    someCol, 
    COUNT(*), 
    GROUP_CONCAT(myTableID SEPARATOR ',') 
FROM myTable 
GROUP BY someCol
```

I would like to use the list of myTableIDs in the third column in a subquery's IN clause.  The following non-working query illustrates this:

```
# this does not work
SELECT
    someCol,
    COUNT(*),
    (    SELECT COUNT(mySubTable.*) 
         FROM mySubTable 
         WHERE mySubTable.foreignID IN GROUP_CONCAT(myTable.myTableID SEPERATOR ',')
    ) AS FOREIGN_COUNT
FROM myTable GROUP BY someCol
```

The `IN GROUP_CONCAT()` part doesn't work because the GROUP_CONCAT() is just returning a string with commas, not an actual list of ids or a subquery.

My question is, is it possible to use the aggregate list of myTableIDs as part of the IN clause of the subquery?

Comment: I think you need to get that info in a variable. The do a prepared statement in the language of your choice

Comment: I am almost embarrassed to show you this, but it is somewhat related. Check out [Appendix C](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34015333)

Comment: What exactly, in plain English, are you trying to do? What's the actual goal?

Comment: @Bohemian: kordiko's answer solved my problem, but I'll explain using an example.  Say you have a Person table and you want to get a list of first names from that table along with a count.  That would be like my first query.  What I'm trying to do is, for each row of that result, I want to know how many of them live in the USA.  For the sake of my situation, let's say the person's country is in a separate many-to-many table on PersonID.  In order to get a count of each first name's USA-status, I was trying to pass the list of PersonIDs for each first name to a subquery's IN-clause. Make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a 'SUM' function do do such a task:

```
SELECT 
    someCol, 
    COUNT(*), 
    GROUP_CONCAT(myTableID SEPARATOR ','),
    SUM( 
         ( select COUNT(*) FROM mySubTable
           WHERE mySubTable.foreignID = myTable.myTableId )
        )
FROM myTable 
GROUP BY someCol;
```

Comment: This is perfect for my purposes.  Thank you!