# Count occurrences of tags by timestamp in mysql

Tags: mysql

For each row of the table shown below, I am trying to create a count of the number of times chronologically that the rate_id has appeared up until the time shown in created.

```
conversions
| rate_id  | created              | valid   | count |
+---------------------------------------------------+
+ 1        | 2016-07-01 11:23:00  | 1       |       |
+ 2        | 2016-07-02 18:58:39  | 1       |       |
+ 2        | 2016-07-02 19:49:20  | 1       |       |
+ 3        | 2016-07-03 18:58:39  | 1       |       |
```

would result in

```
conversions
| rate_id  | created              | valid   | count |
+---------------------------------------------------+
+ 1        | 2016-07-01 11:23:00  | 1       | 1     |
+ 2        | 2016-07-02 18:58:39  | 1       | 1     |
+ 2        | 2016-07-02 19:49:20  | 1       | 2     |
+ 3        | 2016-07-03 18:58:39  | 1       | 1     |
```

I have tried running the following MySQL query, however I feel that there must be a more efficient way to do this and would appreciate your thoughts and suggestions:

```
update conversions a
set a.count = (select sum(valid) from conversions c where c.created <= a.created and c.rate_id = a.rate_id)
where date(a.created) > '2016-05-31';
```

Comment: One would have to show with performance that an update with a join on a derived table gets it faster. Performance may vary from before version 5.7, and at and after 5.7 due to materialized derived tables.

Comment: You could mess around with seeing this rambling answer of mine [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37649350) by testing *covered indexes* and reading the Percona article. Some people have enjoyed wild success with them and haven't suffered much downside on the upsert.