# In mysql simple join query takes long time for excecuting

Tags: mysql, join, query-optimization

retrieving data from three different table using join.The join takes long time to executing in mysql.

Comment: please, paste your query and look [explain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10148851/how-to-optimise-mysql-queries-based-on-explain-plan)

Comment: There is no question in this post.

Comment: It may also help to provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @Alberto Moro please share the explain.

Also you join query can be slow because of numerous reasons like the joins that you are implementing may not be on keys.

When you right Explain before the query it helps you detail out the query so that you can optimise it using the data.